# How to I get rid of Nuget

Tags: azure, nuget

I am coming to the conclusion that nuget is not worth all of the issues it has with source control and deployment.  So how do I get rid of it? I want to go the old route of putting the referenced dlls in the bin folder and doing the configuration changes as normal.

Comment: What do you mean 'get rid of it'? Just don't use it.

Comment: For a rather in-depth examination of these types of issues, you may find it's worth taking a look at an article published by a colleague of mine that talks about the challenges of using NuGet in a professional development organization: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/taking-nuget-to-the-enterprise/

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar issue, and I can to some degree see your point - the packages folder that NuGet creates at my solution level is good in that it collates the required dependencies into a single folder for use by projects in that solution - BUT it does become a problem when our developers try to push the solution code into source control, as I don't want to store an EntityFramework.dll folder with each solution, and particularly with all of the gumph that comes with it.  (Incidentally, I personally don't think that .dlls should even be committed to source control!)

But in terms of your question about getting rid of it, I'm not entirely sure how much it's woven into Visual Studio now, but here's a change you could try out:

Inside Visual Studio, go to the Tools > Options > Package Manager > Package Sources. Un-check the box that makes the 'NuGet official package source' available.  This, in theory, should make the NuGet API unavailable to your IDE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is an option.  Do you have any good links for dealing with all the problems with Nuget? I have been trying to use just the basic stuff and it has been a freaking nightmare.  OAuth uses version 2.0 of razor but the latest mvc uses 3.0. I can't believe I am the only one having this issue right now.

Comment: There are many ways to manage your dependencies outside of using NuGet as this is relatively late to the party in terms of things. I developed an 'Ivy' system using tools from Maven, which have been ported onto the Windows platform. To use this, I have to file a dependency in a particular folder structure, by manufacturer, filename, version number and also file type. This might all sound anal, but I have full control over exactly which version of every .dll is included with any of my projects, with the benefit of none of the dependencies being committed to source control.

Answer (score 1):

My team opted to use NuGet for discovery (we love it for that), separately from our active projects, and to manage our references through another means to achieve control and minimalism. This is how we removed NuGet from those projects:

- First, uninstall the NuGet packages in your projects (optionally re-add your references without NuGet at this point, or at the end)
- In the same folder as your solution file (.sln) there may be a .nuget folder, which you should delete if no other solutions in that folder rely on NuGet.
- In each project folder, delete the packages.config file. If this wasn't checked in to source control, every developer needs to delete packages.config from every project in every branch that is affected.
- In each project file (.csproj), there are two lines in the PropertyGroup section that should be deleted:

  <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">...</SolutionDir>
  <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
- There is also a section at the bottom of each project file (I've seen multiple incarnations at this location, so this is just an example)

  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir).nuget\nuget.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.targets')" />

You have to coordinate this with your team.  If anyone opens a solution that includes projects with packages.config files in their directories, NuGet will undo the manual edits from above; especially if you have Auto-check turned on.